# adding loading indicator for ImageBrush

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have the following code in silverlight for windows phone :

```
 <Border CornerRadius="0" x:Name="brdTest" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="4" Width="100" Height="60">
                                <Border.Background>
                                    <ImageBrush x:Name="backgroundImageBrush" Stretch="Fill">
                                        <ImageBrush.ImageSource>
                                            <BitmapImage x:Name="bmpBackground" UriSource="http://www.images.com/1.jpg">
                                            </BitmapImage>
                                        </ImageBrush.ImageSource>
                                    </ImageBrush>
                                </Border.Background>
                            </Border>
```

How can i add a loading activity indicator from silverlight toolkit in the image place while the image(`http://www.images.com/1.jpg`) loads and remove it when the image has loaded?

Do the images load in a background thread? Or do they block the main UI Thread? (i.e. i would like to use this in a template for lots of list box items)

**UPDATE** I tried this code and loaded a big image (70MP), and while the image was loading, the app's main UI thread didn't froze

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [`ProgressOverlay`](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ProgressOverlay&referringTitle=Documentation), or a [`PerformanceProgressBar`](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-PerformanceProgressBar-in-depth). Here's an example with a `ProgressOverlay`:

```
<Grid>
    <Border CornerRadius="0" x:Name="brdTest" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="4" Width="400" Height="360">
        <Border.Background>
            <ImageBrush x:Name="backgroundImageBrush" Stretch="Fill">
                <ImageBrush.ImageSource>
                    <BitmapImage x:Name="bmpBackground" 
                                 UriSource="http://www.bestmotherofthegroomspeeches.com/wp-content/themes/thesis/rotator/sample-4.jpg"
                                 ImageOpened="bmpBackground_ImageOpened">
                    </BitmapImage>
                </ImageBrush.ImageSource>
            </ImageBrush>
        </Border.Background>
    </Border>

    <Controls:ProgressOverlay 
        x:Name="overlay"
        Width="400" Height="360">
        <Controls:ProgressOverlay.Content>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center">Loading Image</TextBlock>
                <toolkit:PerformanceProgressBar IsIndeterminate="True"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Controls:ProgressOverlay.Content>
    </Controls:ProgressOverlay>
</Grid>
```

And in the `bmpBackground_ImageOpened` event handler you add `overlay.Hide();` which hides the `OverlayProgress`.

This approach seems better than just using a `PerformanceProgressBar` alone, because it gives the user an indication on what's going on.

PS: The `OverlayProgress` didn't work properly for me until I added a `PerformanceProgressBar` in it's "Content" as shown in the code. (try removing it and see if it works for you).

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you very much, as i see, i must download Coding4fun from codeplex (http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/) nonetheless, i would have wanted to have a separate loading item for all the photos, and this approach doesn't appeal to 200+ items with images loading (most likely thread freeze)

Comment: well, if you want a "loading items" that goes away after ALL items are loaded, you can use the same approach, but then use a count, for example, that you increment on each "ImageOpened" and compare to the lists count, and "Hide" the overlay accordingly.

Comment: i would like to have the list displayed (even if the images are not yet downloaded) and instead of the images, some "loading" indicators. Once the images have appeared, the loading instruments should dissapear.

Comment: In that case, I would suggest that you would make this (the code I posted) as a `UserControl`, and then set it as the `ItemTemplate` for your listbox.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh407288%28v=VS.88%29.aspx). Here the author has explained about progress indicators and using different threads using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke 
You could toggle the visibility of the progress bar once done, and display the image.
Hope this helps.

Comment: this isn't what i am looking for. this manages the entire download process, and my code manages the download for me. I need a sort of "finish download" callback (designed for this BitmapImage xaml code) when the image has finished loading.

Answer (score 0):

just added to the BitmapImage : ImageOpened="bmpBackground_ImageOpened" and this calls a method so that i may remove a child ( toolkit loading item ) .

**EDIT**

how can i call for that listbox that contains the image that called "bmpBackground_ImageOpened" to remove a child? Practically i want to call the parent listboxItem of this spacific BitmapImage so that i may remove a child (the loading image).